# What does npm install -E mean?

Tags: npm

While studying Socket.io I encountered this npm command:

```
npm install -E socket.io-client@4.4.0
```

What does the -E tag mean?

Answer (score 2):

npm documentation explains:

```
`-E, --save-exact`: Saved dependencies will be configured with an
  exact version rather than using npm's default semver range
  operator.
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install